# Using から with the verb 言う

Tags: grammar, particle-から

I was reading a manga and a character said this:

> 詳しくは俺から言う事ができない

I'm pretty sure it means "I can't go into details", but I've never seen the structure 「私から言う」 before. When is it acceptable to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「[Name, pronoun, title, etc.] + **から**
>    + 言う、話す、伝{つた}える, etc.」

is often used when:

1) The person chooses (or chooses not) to be the one to bring up the topic.

2) The person is only allowed to give a certain amount of information.

In both cases, the verb will often be in its (positive or negative) potential form.

Thus, the sentence:

> 「詳{くわ}しくは俺{おれ}から言う事ができない。」

would mean (unless the context suggests otherwise):

> "I am not in a position to give you the  details."